# In “我给他打败了”, who defeated whom?

Tags: meaning

Does "我给他打败了" mean "I defeated him" or "I was defeated by him"?

It seems that “我给他骗了” means "I was cheated by him", but "我给他送走了" means "I send him away". In general, if we say "我给他……（动词）了", how to determine which one is the objective, "我" or "他"？

**Edit:** Several people say we do not usually see "我给他送走了". How about this example:

我给他让座了 means “I gave my seat to him” and "I" is the subjective.

Comment: please put the context of "我给他送走了" , though I know the meaning, but the rarely sentence needs a context for understanding.

Comment: See http://www.minghui.org/mh/articles/2011/12/27/%E7%88%B6%E4%BA%B2%E7%9A%84%E8%BD%AC%E5%8F%98-251083.html: “我告诉他你练的那个功不好，我是写在纸上放在他看的气功书那里。后来那个书我给他送走了，我在纸上说：父亲你不要生气。我回家时他看着我什么也没说，只说你把那书烧了我也不管，以后那功我也不练了。” Here I am neither supporting nor against Falungong; I am just providing a possible context.

Answer (score 4):

我给他打败了 usually means 我被他打败了， namely I was defeated by him. And 我给他骗了 follows the same pattern.

我给他送走了 doesn't sound quite right in my opinion. It should be 我把他送走了, meaning I sent him away.

Answer (score 2):

It's a dialect more or less, you won't meet this kind of usage in formal texts.

我把他打败了.

我被他打败了.